# Opening an url with base64 encoded login data using javascript

Tags: javascript, vba, selenium-webdriver, passwords

I wanna login to a password protected site. This site request login data with a prompt. Who can give me an example how I can handle the prompt popup?

An other solutions would be using https://user:password@anysite.com to connect, but I don't prefer this solution as basic authentification will be outdated soon for security reasons. IE and Edge already disabled that possibility.

Maybe last possibility could be to open a new tab using a script like:

```
    bot.ExecuteScript "window.open(arguments[0])", "https://anysite.com/"
```

I know how I have to encode login data, but I find no script example using encoded login data. It would be great when you can provide an example script too.

Warm regards

Comment: Why `VBA` tag in this question?

Comment: yes, because I will send the javaspript via vba. depending on the solution I will use vba to create the base64-coded basic information. but therefore I already have a solution